# Sending AJAX post request to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So here is my AJAX code using JQuery:

```
$('#button-upload').on('click', function(){
 if( sendSMSArr.length > 0 ){ 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'manager/smsendr4.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'distribution': sendSMSArr},
    success: function(response){  

      }
    });
  }
});
```

The request isn't registered in the network.

Secondly, I'm not sure how can I collect this data with PHP using $_POST.

Comment: Are you sure the `if()` is true?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a php newbie. Here is a snippet of code you can use to retrive the ajax data.
Here is the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) to the documentation about the global variable `$_POST` I suggest you to read it.
Another useful [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) about the predefined variables in php

JS code:

```
$('#button-upload').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
     if( sendSMSArr.length > 0 ){ 
      $.ajax({
        url: 'manager/smsendr4.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'distribution': sendSMSArr},
        success: function(response){  
          console.log(response);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['distribution'])){
# I've added a sanitization filter, but you can omit it if you don't need to pass the data to a database.
$dist = filter_var($_POST['distribution'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
# put your logics here after you got the distribution $_POST variable value.
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, but still my biggest problem right now is that the AJAX request isn't registered in the network (inside the devTool)

Comment: Have you tried to send an echo as response from the script?Is your php console log any error?

Comment: This request is fired after pressing the "send" button, hence the $('#button-upload')

Comment: Try to inspect your app code using this chrome tool `chrome://net-internals/#events`